# Changing application language

Tags: android, kotlin, setlocale

I'm trying to change my application language in runtime. I have checked several posts and my code now looks like:

```
if(position == 0){//Position 0 of an array to select the language
  val locale = Locale("es_ES")
  val config = applicationContext.resources.configuration
  config.setLocale(locale)
  applicationContext.createConfigurationContext(config)
}
```

I have a values-es directory where I have my own strings.xml file with strings translated. Anyway, it seems like it doesn't change anything.

I repeat I tried and checked a lot of posts in Stack Overflow but I don't know where I'm failing. 
Thanks in advance, I'm open to any question due to my bad english.

**Second try:**

I've been tryng and now my code looks like this:

```
val locale = Locale("es")
Locale.setDefault(locale)
val config = applicationContext.resources.configuration
config.setLocale(locale)
applicationContext.resources.configuration.setTo(config)
Log.d("Configuration",config.toString())
Log.d("Language",config.locales.toLanguageTags())
```

And the debug messages are :

```
D/Configuration: {1.0 310mcc260mnc [es] ldltr sw411dp w683dp h387dp 420dpi nrml land finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1794, 1080) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1794, 1080) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined} s.40}


D/Language: es
```

But my strings doesn't change and my app keeps using the strings(en) file.

Comment: can you post the full code

Comment: The code is so extensive, and I checked that this part of the code is executed so I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: okay, let me answer you.

Comment: try es instead of es_ES

Comment: and restart the activity

Comment: Isn't working this way also

Comment: I have posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
String languageToLoad = "es"; // your language
                Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                Intent refresh = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(refresh);
                finish();
```

Comment: I tried to write down the same on kotlin but it doesn't works, sorry and thanks.

Comment: You need to use a LocalHelper for this

Comment: Here is the running code you should take an example of https://github.com/sureshjoshi/android-locale-example

Comment: I tried something new, edited the first post, thanks for your time.